# How do you set a minimum number of characters for Bash tab completion?

Tags: bash, tab-completion

Is there a way to set a minimum number of characters to Bash's tab completion?

My reason is that I often accidentally press the tab key on an empty command line and it takes forever to load the command list.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell bash/completion to NOT try completion for an empty entry through the use of the 'no_empty_cmd_completion' shell option.

In your .bashrc (or alternate), enter this command:

```
shopt -s no_empty_cmd_completion
```

Exit your bash session and restart (or '**source .bashrc**'), and pressing TAB at an empty prompt will just ignore you.

You can type the command at the prompt if you want to try it out beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> I often accidentally press the tab key on an empty command line and it takes forever to load the command list.

```
complete -E
```

can solve above problem, but to figure out the character specific limit is difficult, since it might be inside libraries.

Since we have not specified either directory ( `-d` ) or file ( `-f` ), it will not search for neither file nor directory.